# beautifulsoup4 - grab Sibling element if Sibling present

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The most common repetitive structure of the HTML is:

```
  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is possible for you
   </span>
  </p>
```

in such situations I grab the text `it is possible for you`

Occasionally (i.e., not always), the `<p>` of `class="Standard"` has a sibling `<p>` of `class="P3"`, like so:

```
  <p class="P3">
   (to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)
  </p>
```

When this `<p>` of `class="P3"` is present, I want to additionally grab the text inside it, e.g. here I would additionally grab: `(to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)`

**My question** is, given this kind of structure:

```
<div>
...
  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is possible for you
   </span>
  </p>

  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is acceptable for me
   </span>
  </p>

  <p class="P3">
   (to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)
  </p>
...
</div>
```

How can I produce output like this:

```
it is possible for you
it is acceptable for me
(to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)
```

Currently, I've managed to do this:

```
p_standards = soup.find_all("p", class_ = "Standard")

for p_standard in p_standards:
    p_english = p_standard.find("span", class_="T3")
    print(p_english.contents[0])
```

And the output I get is:

```
it is possible for you
it is acceptable for me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

**Python Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
text = '''
<div>

  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is possible for you
   </span>
  </p>

  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is acceptable for me
   </span>

  </p>
  <p class="P3">
   (to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)
  </p>

</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,features='html.parser')
p_standards = soup.find_all("p", class_ = "Standard")

for p_standard in p_standards:
    p_english = p_standard.find('span',attrs={'class':'T3'})
    nextSibling = p_standard.find_next_sibling()
    print(p_english.text)
    if(nextSibling.attrs['class'][0] == 'P3' and nextSibling.name == 'p'):
      print(nextSibling.text)
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/HighTurbulentScope)

**Explanation :**

- In order to get the `class` value within the find_next_sibling's
  returned element i had to search into the variables of the instance
  its self as there is no doc that mentions it on the official website
  so i printed `nextSibling.__dict__.keys()`
- the `0` index is because the class attribute's type is an array

Comment: There's a typo in the `html` in your example. The `<p class="P3">` element is not supposed to be nested inside the second `<p class="Standard">` element. It's a sibling to it.

Comment: If you have a minute, I'd appreciate if you could please clarify why you needed to do `.attrs['class'][0]`. What's the significance of the `[0]` please? Thanks. (Is this covered in the BeautifulSoup4 documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ ?)

Comment: explanation section has been added, i hope it's helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more efficient to use css Or syntax and an adjacent sibling combinator to perform this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div>
...
  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is possible for you
   </span>
  </p>

  <p class="Standard">
   <span class="T3">
    it is acceptable for me
   </span>
  </p>

  <p class="P3">
   (to ask a question in Spanish, you just use inflection)
  </p>
...
</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.Standard, .Standard + .P3')]
print(items)
```